# Error while installing R packages : Tcl/Tk support is not available on this system

Tags: r, installation

I am using Linux- fedora 14 64 bit machine. While installing some of R packages , eg : DEGseq and sqldf , I am facing this error. I manually install all tcl and tk devel and core libraries using yum but the problem still persisting.

The error i am encountering while installing packages:

```
Warning: S3 methods ‘$.tclvar’, ‘$<-.tclvar’, ‘as.character.tclObj’, ‘as.character.tclVar’, ‘as.double.tclObj’, ‘as.integer.tclObj’, ‘as.logical.tclObj’, ‘as.raw.tclObj’, ‘print.tclObj’, ‘[[.tclArray’, ‘[[<-.tclArray’, ‘$.tclArray’, ‘$<-.tclArray’, ‘names.tclArray’, ‘names<-.tclArray’, ‘length.tclArray’, ‘length<-.tclArray’, ‘tclObj.tclVar’, ‘tclObj<-.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue.default’, ‘tclvalue.tclObj’, ‘tclvalue.tclVar’, ‘tclvalue<-.default’, ‘tclvalue<-.tclVar’, ‘close.tkProgressBar’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: Tcl/Tk support is not available on this system
Error : package/namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘gsubfn’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘gsubfn’
* removing ‘/home/xuserL/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/gsubfn’
ERROR: dependency ‘gsubfn’ is not available for package ‘sqldf’
* removing ‘/home/xuser/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.15/sqldf’
```

I am unable to find the solution even after googling about this error.

Please tell me the set of steps i need to follow in order to sort out this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check out: https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck ! After installing dev packages for tcl and tk on my linux machine, i recompile the R (15 version) distribution. It is working fine.